# RegEx for only space is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am checking if only white spaces is entered. My code is like

```
 if (!emailDetails[0].description.match(/\s/g)) {
            isValidCase = false;
            $('#email_desc_' + id + '').removeClass('hidden');
        }
```

It works fine in **chrome** but not in **IE**.

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: Try `/\s/.test(str)`

Comment: What is your test string that you're expecting to match? As it is, this will match any string that contains a space.

Comment: Version is IE-10. `/^\S+([\s\xA0]|&nbsp;)+/, ''` is working fine.

Comment: `/^\S+([\s\xA0]|&nbsp;)+/, ''` works fine. If i enter only white space, it is detecting. but if i enter white space and then some string, it fails. Can you help me with that!!

Comment: You are right @NevStokes. I am expecting strings only. but as i explained above, string after empty spaces is not working.

Comment: Issue is fixed. Below is the code